# Segmentation Fault When Using The Push Back Function for a Vector

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, std

So I am trying to build a hash table with a custom hash function from scratch and I ran into a segmentation fault issue while testing the insert function. If I read the gdb output correctly, the problem occurred when trying to do a push back on a boolean vector in my wn_to_bool function (takes a whole number and converts it into a vector of booleans). I have been trying to debug this issue for a while but have not reached a solution. Any help would be gladly appreciated, I can update the post with the rest of the code referenced in the debug if necessary. Thank you in advance.

**GDB output with no new operator**

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000055555555668b in std::vector<bool, std::allocator<bool> >::push_back (this=0x0, __x=false) at /usr/include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_bvector.h:955
955             if (this->_M_impl._M_finish._M_p != this->_M_impl._M_end_addr())
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000055555555668b in std::vector<bool, std::allocator<bool> >::push_back (this=0x0, __x=false) at /usr/include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_bvector.h:955
#1  0x0000555555556302 in HashTable<int, int>::wn_to_bool (this=0x7fffffffe3f0, wn=2) at Data_Structures/Hash_Table.cpp:186
#2  0x0000555555556230 in HashTable<int, int>::hashfct (this=0x7fffffffe3f0, key=2) at Data_Structures/Hash_Table.cpp:146
#3  0x0000555555556163 in HashTable<int, int>::insert (this=0x7fffffffe3f0, key=2, value=3) at Data_Structures/Hash_Table.cpp:53
#4  0x0000555555555b0f in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe4f8) at main.cpp:16
```

**GDB output with new operator**

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff7ab8f25 in raise () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7ab8f25 in raise () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7aa2897 in abort () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff7b03758 in __malloc_assert () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff7b05f6f in sysmalloc () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff7b06d32 in _int_malloc () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#5  0x00007ffff7b07e84 in malloc () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#6  0x00007ffff7e47cba in operator new (sz=40) at /build/gcc/src/gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/new_op.cc:50
#7  0x000055555555633d in HashTable<int, int>::wn_to_bool (this=0x7fffffffe3f0, wn=2) at Data_Structures/Hash_Table.cpp:181
#8  0x0000555555556230 in HashTable<int, int>::hashfct (this=0x7fffffffe3f0, key=2) at Data_Structures/Hash_Table.cpp:146
#9  0x0000555555556163 in HashTable<int, int>::insert (this=0x7fffffffe3f0, key=2, value=3) at Data_Structures/Hash_Table.cpp:53
#10 0x0000555555555b0f in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe4f8) at main.cpp:16
```

**wn_to_bool function** (*Please note v is initially an empty vector so the insert function will not work*)

```
template <typename K, typename V> std::vector<bool>* HashTable<K,V>::wn_to_bool(long wn)
{
    std::vector<bool>* v;

    while(wn != 0)
    {
        if(wn % 2 == 0)
            v->push_back(false);
        else
            v->push_back(true);

        wn = wn / 2;
    }

    return v; 
}
```

Comment: `v` is uninitialized, you've got a dangling pointer => undefined reference. Why are you using pointers to vectors? Also careful, `vector<bool>` is rather weird.

Comment: "takes a whole number and converts it into a vector of booleans" This is of rather dubious utility. Why do you need a vector of booleans?

Answer (score 2):

> Please note v is initially an empty vector

It is not. It is an unitialised pointer. There is no actual vector in sight.

Do not use raw pointers.

Leaving the utility of such a functon aside, here is a way to write it.

```
template <typename K, typename V> 
std::vector<bool> // no pointer
HashTable<K,V>::wn_to_bool(long wn)
{
    std::vector<bool> v; //no pointer
    while(wn != 0)
    {
        if(wn % 2 == 0)
            v.push_back(false);
        else
            v.push_back(true);
        wn = wn / 2;
    }
    return v; 
}
```

> so the insert function will not work)

`insert` works perfectly well with an empty vector, e.g.. `vector<int> v; v.insert(v.begin(), 42)`.

Comment: I'm sorry but where is insert? the insert method that you see in the backtrace is for the ```HashTable``` class but not the ```std::vector```. This question has nothing to do with ```insert``` method.

Comment: @SoheilArmin OP incorrectly claims that `insert` does not work with an empty *vector*. I am addressing this claim.

Comment: It's obvious that an empty vector is a vector which ```begin()``` equals to ```end()``` and ```push_back``` actually means ```insert(end(),val)```. So you are absolutely true.

Answer (score 1):

when you do `std::vector<bool>* v`, you will have an uninitialized pointer to `std::vector<bool>`. It means that `v` has some arbitary value without being assigned to any allocated memory address.
You need to create a `new` vector and assign it to `v`.

```
template <typename K, typename V> std::vector<bool>* HashTable<K,V>::wn_to_bool(long wn)
{
    auto v = new std::vector<bool>();

    for(;wn!=0;wm/=2)
        v->push_back(wn % 2 != 0);

    return v; 
}
```

You won't need `if` statement as you are directly using the result of the boolean statement. You just need to push back `wn%2 != 0` which is much more efficient than using `if`. You may also use `for` loop to have more readability as you will write the whole logic in a single line of code.

As advised on comments, creating object instances in heap memory (aka using `new`) should be used with enough care because you will have to take care of deleting the allocated memory when you won't need it anymore or it will cause memory leaks. Using [***smart pointers***](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) is highly recommended instead.

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific earlier but I did try the new operator using your method and std::vector<bool> *v = new std::vector<bool> but they lead to the abort described in the gdb output above (with new operator).

Comment: @patelvrajn The answer is correct according to your exposed code (IMHO). If you tried something else which didn't work as well - that's another question. _Please note v is initially an empty vector so the insert function will not work_ No, it's not an empty vector it's an uninitialized pointer (as correctly pointed out). Inserting into an initially empty vector should work.

Comment: @Scheff Inserting according to the STD documentation does not work if the vector is empty (contains no booleans in this case). The insert operation requires an iterator, an iterator cannot point anywhere if there are no objects to point to.

Comment: Please do not advvise unsuspecting newbies to use new and pointers. It is NOT a good idea.

Comment: Thats the problem, when teaching kids java as their first language... everything is "new" :)

Comment: You might present an alternative solution returning a `vector` by value to come around the concerns about `new`.